# Javascript automatically change string

Tags: javascript

Hi im new to javascript and im trying to figure out how to append a string after an allotted amount of time.

```
After 3 secs append string (How)
After 3 secs append string (are)
After 3 secs append string (you)
After 3 secs append string (?)
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Please heed @SLaks' comment and **do not** pass a string to `setTimeout`. It's `eval` in disguise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <span id="mySpan"></span>
    </body>
    <script>
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML += "How ";', 3000);
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML += "are ";', 6000);
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML += "you";', 9000);
        setTimeout('document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML += "?";', 12000);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Please do not advise passing strings to `setTimeout`. It's `eval` in disguise.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout).

```
var text = 'How are you ?'.split(' '),
    delay = 3000;

function generateCallback(text) {
    return function () {
        alert(text);
    };
}

for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(generateCallback(text[i]), delay*(i+1));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/dYBUs/

Answer (score 0):

As a modification of current answers, a single `setInterval` call can be used, cancelling it when all words are displayed:

```
// s is string to display
// interval is the time in milliseconds between adding words
// id is the id or reference to a DOM element to display s in
function staggerDisplay(s, interval, id) {

  var el = typeof id == 'string'? document.getElementById(id) : id;
  var sBits = s.split(' ');
  var numWords = sBits.length;
  var i = 0;
  var intervalRef = setInterval(
    function () {
      if (i < numWords) {
        el.innerHTML += ' ' + sBits[i++];
      } else {
        clearInterval(intervalRef);
      }
    }, interval);
}
```